# Description of intonation variation with exclamative sentences (various cases envisaged)

Tags: grammar, pronunciation

In the question "[description of intonation variation with declarative, interrogative, propositive, imperative, exclamative, …?](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/2413/description-of-intonation-variation-with-declarative-interrogative-propositive?rq=1)" topo morto said that exclamative intonations intonations are often specific to the particular exclamation(s). The best to learn intonations would be probably to hear them but it's a lot of difficulties to find examples of spoken exclamations in korean and to hear them. Therefore, I am asking for descriptions with words of the intonations. I have made a list of exclamative sentences hereafter. I hope every case of intonation are in this list.
Well, how can the intonation variation of those exclamative sentences be described ?

1. 좋습니다 !
2. 아주 맛있는데요 !
3. 주문하신 차를 가져왔는데요.
4. 편지를 프랑스로 부치고 싶은데요.
5. 기분이 별론데.
6. 해는 다 져 가는데 !
7. 뭔데요 ?
8. 오래간만에 오셨네요.
9. 현대 통신 단어는 다 외래어네요 !
10. 별소리 다하네.
11. 웬일이예요. 이렇게 우연히 여기서 만나다니 !
12. 높구나 !
13. 비싸 구나 !
14. 보는구나 !
15. 다들 몰라보게 변했더군요.
16. 컴퓨터는 저장하는 것이라기보다는 저금하는 것이라고 할 수 있겠네요 !
17. 요즘 정신없이 바쁘시겠네요.
18. 어디 봐, 뭔데 ?
19. 어머나 !
20. 저런! 어쩌면! 어머나!
21. 참 !
22. 나 원 참!
23. 아이구 !
24. 저런,아이구 !
25. 어쩌면 이렇게 더울까 !
26. 어쩌면 그 사람이 올지도 몰라.
27. 어찌나 사람이 많은지요 !
28. 그 녀석 행동이 어찌나 느릿하던지!
29. 물론 !
30. 물론이죠 !
    31)이런!

Comment: It's like describe music with letters. Haha.

Comment: As TING says, describing intonation is hard; would you be happy with recordings as part of an answer?

Comment: *very* general rule of thumb: exclamations have emphasis on the first two letters, interrogative have intonation curling upwards at the end, and declarative has either a monotonic or falling ending.

Comment: Topo morto has had a good idea. I would be very happy with recordings. But is there a mean to put recordings on the forum ? 
Moreover, I think that graphics may be a good idea. Like recordings, graphics should enable comparison between various cases of exclamative sentences and between exclamative sentences and the other kind of sentences.
I think that graphics must show how the strengh and the acuteness of the voice varie, and also how much time is taken for each syllabes or phoneme (rapidity variation of the speech).
But is there a mean to put graphics on the forum ?

Comment: Can someone or someone else make the above evocated recordings and graphics ? (if they don't exist yet ?)
Can someone or somebody else put them on the internet ?
Can someone or somebody else indicate their internet adresse(s) ?Can someone or somebody else add other exclamative sentences to show the missing intonation cases, if some intonation cases aren't in the exclamative sentences of the list that I have given ?
Can someone or somebody else give a classification of the various case of intonation in the exclamative sentences ?

Comment: 23) 아이구 !!  This is an excamation no matter how you say it, I'm fairly certain...  19) 어머나 as well, and all the 구나, 군(요)s also are always classified that way.

Comment: @TripleDragonVolant It is is possible to add images - [**this**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post) is a very old post but gives the general idea. I imagine it would take a long time to make graphics for all sentences, which is why I thought recordings would be quicker. These can't be hosted directly on the site, but could be put on (e.g. youtube or soundcloud, and linked to).

Comment: @TripleDragonVolant by the way I converted your answer to comments - on stack exchange (unlike 'forum'-like sites), answers are supposed to be for actual answers to the question; discussion can be had in comments (like here), [**chat**](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41465/korean-language) or [**meta**](http://meta.korean.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: K-drama or a Korean tv show would be good reference for this. They tend to exaggerate but that makes the intonation even more pronounced.

Comment: This closely relates to [K-ToBI](https://linguistics.ucla.edu/people/jun/ktobi/k-tobi.html). Please read it focusing on the "IP final boundary tones." And if you have audio files, you may use [Praat](http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/) to visualize their tones. I use it to learn a language.

Comment: It needs to be noted that the most significant still remaining part of regional accents in Korea is intonation of sentences such as the ones provided here. Someone who has lived their entire life on the countryside near Busan is going to pronounce many of them differently than someone from Seoul. The second I tried to think about how I would put the intonation into text I realized that my accent would get into the way of a "representative" translation.

Answer (score 0):

I'll use Korean phrase : 평서형(declarative)ㆍ감탄형(exclamative)ㆍ의문형(interrogative)ㆍ명령형(imperative)ㆍ청유형(propositive).

First, I'll classify these.

1. 좋습니다! : 감탄형
2. 아주 맛있는데요! : 감탄형
3. 주문하신 차를 가져왔는데요. : 평서형 or weak 의문형
4. 편지를 프랑스로 부치고 싶은데요. : 평서형 or weak 의문형
5. 기분이 별론데. : 평서형, maybe. (murmuring)
6. 해는 다 져 가는데! : somewhat unnatural. can be 감탄형.
7. 뭔데요? : 의문형
8. 오래간만에 오셨네요. : can be both 평서형 or weak 감탄형.
9. 현대 통신 단어는 다 외래어네요! : 감탄형
10. 별소리 다하네. : 평서형
11. 웬일이예요. 이렇게 우연히 여기서 만나다니! 의문형, then 감탄형
12. 높구나! : 감탄형
13. 비싸구나! : 감탄형
14. 보는구나! : 감탄형
15. 다들 몰라보게 변했더군요. : 평서형 or weak 감탄형
16. 컴퓨터는 저장하는 것이라기보다는 저금하는 것이라고 할 수 있겠네요! : 감탄형
17. 요즘 정신없이 바쁘시겠네요. : 평서형 or weak 감탄형
18. 어디 봐, 뭔데? : 명령형, then 의문형
19. 어머나! : 감탄형
20. 저런! 어쩌면! 어머나! : 감탄형
21. 참! : 감탄형
22. 나 원 참! : 감탄형
23. 아이구! : 감탄형
24. 저런,아이구! : 감탄형
25. 어쩌면 이렇게 더울까! : 감탄형
26. 어쩌면 그 사람이 올지도 몰라. : 평서형
27. 어찌나 사람이 많은지요! : 감탄형
28. 그 녀석 행동이 어찌나 느릿하던지! : 감탄형
29. 물론! : 감탄형
30. 물론이죠! : 감탄형
31. 이런! : 감탄형

...But it can be pronounced differently depend on situation or who speak it.

example of '청유형' : '혹시 물좀 가져다 주실 수 있나요?'(Can you give me a water?)
example of '명령형' : '공부해.'/'공부해!'(Study./Study!)